# Recaptcha V2 is not working, more and more bots keep spamming the entry

Tags: php, codeigniter, recaptcha, grecaptcha

I do not know whats wrong with my code, I am using code igniter framework and I have implemented recaptcha like so:

In the view:
`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="***********************************"></div>`

In the submitted form response page:

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
                {
                        $secret = '???*******************************??????';
                        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
                        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
                        if($responseData->success)
                        {
                            $succMsg = 'Your registration request has submitted successfully.';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'CAPTCHA Verification Failed');
                            redirect('User/login_view');;
                        }
                }
```

Despite the implementation, I am getting upto 15 spam registrations per day. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

reCaptcha (and any other captcha) won't prevent spam, it will only prevent bots from using the form. There are [captcha farms](https://2captcha.com) out there with real workers solving captchas. To prevent spam registrations, the captcha must be combined with other forms of validation such as one time passwords via SMS.

Comment: The Spam looks like it is bot generated the characters are all out of whack! I agree that the OTP method is most effective though but my solution is at a non-profit stage so utilization of such resources will be too expensive. Thanks for the idea though! :)

Comment: Bots can use captcha farms to fill the captcha. There are several services that provides free SMS, Firebase for example: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Thanks Elias! I didnt know there were free options like firebase! This really helps!

Comment: @Kwikfox you're welcome. If that solves your problem, can you mark the question as answered?

Comment: Yes this is answered